# Like Clause over an 'Element' - ORACLE APEX

Tags: sql, sql-like, apex

I encounter some problems that i don't understand with APEX.... Well, let's be specific.

- I ve got a select element retrieving a top 50 of most liked url (P11_URL). This is populate by a table view, TOp_Domains.
- I create an element called "Context" that have to print all text containing the URL selected by the user from the element select. Those Texts come from another table, let's say "twitter_post".

I create a dynamic action (show only) with this sql/statement:

```
Select TXT, NB_RT, RANK
from myschema.twitter_post
where TXT like '%:P11_URL%'
group by TXT, NB_RT, RANK
```

.... and it doesn't work... I think APEX don't like `like` clause... But i don't know how to do. Let's keep in min an url could have been shared by multiple Tweets, that's why this element "context" is important for me. 
I tried to bypass the problem by building a State (in french Statique) and a dynamic action that will refresh the state but it doesn't work neither... bouhououououou

TriX

Comment: You are looking for a txt containing the string `':P11_URL'`? Or is this supposed to be a bind variable? Then you should probably not put this inside quotes, but rather concatenate this variable content with the percent signs: `like '%' || :P11_URL || '%'`.

Comment: thank you Shanid for review suggestion!

Comment: @Thorsten, yes i'm looking for txt containning the url string. I try and i tell u!

Comment: @Thorsten.... well it doesn't work... i really don't know why...

Comment: Are you getting some results in the 'Context' element. Can you tell when the DA will be fired?

Comment: @MAdona: no there is no result in context and dynamic action is fired when user select an url from the select P11_URL. I also modified sequences, thinking it was a problem of sequence organization but... no success...

Comment: Ok lets exemplify. When i test this code into sql developer:   [code]select s.label, h.rn, p.titre 
from sample_brazil s, fb_post p, top_hashtags h
where p.titre like '%#grevegeral%'
and s.id = p.id_entity
group by s.label, h.rn, p.titre;[code] It works perfectly. I want a DA populating what comes between the "%" ... and that's what it's not working ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the 'P11_URL'  and create DA. Event :change, Item:P11_URL. As the true action of the DA, select 'Set Value'. Write your query in the sql stmt area. In the page items to submit, select 'P11_URL' . In the 'Affected Items': select 'Context'.
Query should be :
    Select TXT, NB_RT, RANK
    from myschema.twitter_post
    where TXT like '%' || :P11_URL || '%'
    group by TXT, NB_RT, RANK

Comment: Well... i really don't understand APEX tell me "Error: parsererror - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: I have created a sample app(with some similar scenario) for you here:[Mydemo](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/) . Workspace:MADONAM,username:meetmadshere@gmail.com,password:guest .

Comment: If ur problem is not addressed there, please modify MyDemo app so that I can try to solve that.

Comment: Thank you very much Madona. I tried to start from scratch yesterday night. Now i have something that work.... partially... welll...hem... not sure. I explain: i create a select list which return the result of a view in my database. I succeded creating a dynamic action that refesh function of this select list a dynamic report showing posts containing the value selected in the select list....Well great it works! But results show in he report are wrong.... Maybe i don't understand the selectlist  mechanism?

Comment: are you using interactive report to display the result? did you give 'P1_URL' in the 'page items to submit' below the sql query for the report? and u are using  'refresh' DA on change of value in the select list  to refresh the report?

Comment: Hello yep evrything is ok in this way... i can't understand... when it works the same query in sqldeveloper and the result print by apex are completely different....there is thg that i can't understand....

Comment: pls check the session state once you refresh the report to ensure that P1_URL is having the newly selected value.

Answer (score 0):

So 
Thanks to @Madona... Their example made me realised my mistake. I wrote the answer here for futher help if somebody encouter the same porblem. 
A list select element get as arguments a display value (the one you want to be shown in your screen.... if you want so....^^ ) and a return value (in order, I think to linked dynamic actions). So to solved my problem i had to shape my sql statement as:

```
select hashtags d, hastags r
from my table
order by 1
```

[let s say that now in Apex it s an object called P1_HASHTAGS]

First step problem solving. 
In fact, the ranking as second value, as i put into my sql statement was making some mitsakens into my 'Where like' clause search... well...  Newbie am i!

Second step was to correctly formate the sql statement receiving the datas from my select lov (P1_HASHTAGS) into my interactive report. As shown here:

```
Select Id, hashtags
from my table
where txt like '%'||:P1_HASHTAGS||'%'
```

And it works!
Thank you Madona your example helped me figure my mistakes!